# How can integrate tinypic with ckeditor (wysiwyg)?

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, question2answer

I am having website that uses Question2answer Script,now what i want is to integrate tinypic to upload images ? 
How is it possible in my site is using wysiwyg editor.

Thanks alot in advance for helping

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
tinypic_layout = 'narrow';
tinypic_type = 'both';
tinypic_links = 'html';
tinypic_language = 'en';
tinypic_search = 'true';
tinypic_autoload = true;
</script>
<script src="http://plugin.tinypic.com/j/plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

THIS IS THE CODE NOW I WANT TO ATTACH THIS IN MY CKEDITOR

Answer (score 0):

Check out KCFinder on this site: http://www.webidsupport.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-5279.html?s=fd245ddb0b2ed49e1c373bc5d56833c7

It does what you are asking for.

Comment: No sorry , I want to use tinypic instead of uploading Images to my own server , Visitors will click on Upload button after they will have option to upload pic (Tinypic) http://tinypic.com/developer.php Now i want this code in the last of developer page to attach with my ckeditor